# How can I keep requests session on web2py?

Tags: session, web2py

I develop a gateway server use web2py.

like this:

> user <---> gateway server (web2py) <---> data server

When user request to gateway server, the gateway server will request to the data server.

This data server need use the same session to request the data.

My code in gateway server:

```
def test1():
    session = requests.Session()
    resp = session.post(DATA_SERVER_URL1, data=payload1)

def test2():
    session = requests.Session()
    resp = session.post(DATA_SERVER_URL2, data=payload2)
```

I need to keep session from test1().

When user request test2(), it need use same session to request to data server.

Can it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are creating a new `requests.Session` object on every web2py request, so there is no persistence from one web2py request to another. I belief the `Session` object of the `requests` library can be pickled, so you should be able to store it in the web2py `session` (note, you should not name an object "session" in your web2py code, as there is already a "session" object available in the global namespace).

```
def test1():
    session.rs = session.rs or requests.Session()
    resp = session.rs.post(DATA_SERVER_URL1, data=payload1)

def test2():
    session.rs = session.rs or requests.Session()
    resp = session.rs.post(DATA_SERVER_URL2, data=payload2)
```

In the above code, note that `session` is the web2py `session` object, not a `Session` object created by the `requests` library. On each request, the above checks whether a `requests.Session` object is stored in the web2py session -- if so, it uses that object, and otherwise, it creates a new one (which will be used within subsequent web2py requests from the same user).